# Selecting ubuntu 12.04 restarts my HP 540 laptop

Tags: hp, system, restart

Every time I select Ubuntu 12.04 when booting my HP 540 laptop, the machine restarts. How can I fix this, so I can successfully boot my Ubuntu system?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Toshiba laptop. After some investigation, it seems that the "wake up on lid being open" is enabled and, of course, the lid is open just after it shuts down. A workround for this is:

```
sudo echo LID > /proc/acpi/wakeup
```

This can be put in `/etc/rc.local`

Comment: Commands like `sudo echo TEXT > root-owned-file` **don't actually succeed**. `echo` runs as root, then its output is redirected *as the non-root user* to the file, which the non-root user cannot write to. There are a number of alternatives that do work; one of them is `echo LID | sudo tee /proc/acpi/wakeup` (with an optional `> /dev/null` tacked on to the end if you need it to not write to [stdout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdout#Standard_output_.28stdout.29)). Another option is `sudo sh -c 'echo LID > /proc/acpi/wakeup'`.